# BHO Extension for IE11 on Windows 64-bit registering but not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, 64-bit, bho, regasm

I have been going at this for days. I have created a IE add-on that registers and works great on 32-bit IE. My problem occurs when I try to get it running on 64-bit Windows 7. As I found out, IE on 64 runs both 32 and 64. So trying to run my add-on by registering the 32-bit dll using the 32-bit regasm gets it working. However, Registering the 64-bit dll using the 64 bit regasm doesnt work. If i run IE in enhanced protected mode, the add-on works.

I am trying to get the IE to run my 64-bit add-on without enhanced protected mode on as other add-ons that are required only run on 32-bit EI and thus are disabled/incompatible when using enhanced mode. I also need to be able to run my DLL in 64-bit and NOT in 32-bit as I am using my dll to communicate with drivers/firmware that have to be in 64-bit so they would work on windows.

Without Enhanced mode on:

*I tried registering 64bit BHO Dll with regasm 64
-----Didnt run my add-on but I could see it in the manage add-ons
*I tried registering the ANY CPU BHO Dll with regasm 64 and 32
-----Could see the add on and run it but when trying to call the hardware it failed because the hardware requires to be called from 64-bit. (got missing dependencies...)

Here is a copy of my code minus the extensions

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EyeBank_API;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Expando;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IEPlugin
{
    [
    ComVisible(true),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
    Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352")
    ]
    public interface IObjectWithSite
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]object site);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite);
    }


    [
        ComVisible(true),
        Guid("2159CB25-EF9A-54C1-B43C-E30D1A4A8277"),
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("MyExtension"),
        ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IExtension))

    ]
    public class BHO : IObjectWithSite, IExtension
    {
        private SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowser;

        public int SetSite(object site)
        {
            if (site != null)
            {
                webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)site;
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete +=
                  new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
                  this.OnDocumentComplete);
            }
            else
            {
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete -=
                  new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(
                  this.OnDocumentComplete);
                webBrowser = null;
            }

            return 0;

        }

        public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
        {
            IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
            int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
            Marshal.Release(punk);
            return hr;
        }

        public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic window = webBrowser.Document.parentWindow;
                IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)window;
                windowEx.AddProperty("MyExtension");
                window.myExtension = this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        public string CallHardware()
        {
            bool capture = true;
            string result = Library.Call_Hardware_Connect(capture);
            return result;
        }


        public const string BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME =
   "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\" +
   "CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey =
              Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);

            if (registryKey == null)
                registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
                                        BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME);

            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
            RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

            if (ourKey == null)
            {
                ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
            }

            ourKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1,RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            registryKey.Close();
            ourKey.Close();
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey =
              Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);
            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            if (registryKey != null)
                registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
        }

    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("B9BBD37E-510C-4e7c-9ADD-222B72752E0D")]
    public interface IExtension
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string CallHardware();
    }
}
```

Managed to get it working on both. However some websites, that run Java Applet, cannot call my extension. It works on every site, I can call the function normally, however, when i tried to run it from the java applet site it doesnt work. I tried everything.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I a having the same issue.